# Duplicate a sketch on a spiral like array of lines in solidworks

Tags: solidworks, hinge

This one is gonna be hard for me to explain, but I hope you will get it

I have this sketch:
[image: part]

Each side of this part is half of it, to be easily duplicate / mirror / pattern
Important to note the both ends of this chain needs to be just the half (so in IRL can be connected to a round object and glued together)
This is how a full part looks (made from two half's) (sorry for the mass, mirroring it cause all this chaos):
[image: joined part]

And I want to duplicate 40~ times it to this shape that I created:

[image: spiral]

The reason for it to be a spiral and not a a round circle is so save space on the mold

some guidelines and restrictions:

1. each hinge need to be between 185-195 degrees, preferably as little as much variations (although necessary to achieve the spiral)
2. Need to retain the ability to change the length (125mm here) , width (17mm) and number of parts
3. ends need to be the half shaped
4. if you have another way that is more efficient then manually doing the spiral it will be amazing

Really hope that its clear enough, appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: You need to use sketch blocks for something like this.

Comment: Can just import the block and set it to be parallel to each line and coincident where relevant.

Comment: The master strikes again!
Thanks, I thought about it, but its highly manual and not modular, I thought that maybe there is a better faster way

Comment: Not sure - could experiment with curve driven pattern etc, but the alternating straight-bend-straight of your specific application makes me not sure it would work